# My background image disappeared when I pushed my website to GitHub

Tags: css, github, background-image

I have non idea why it vanished. I can see it when I look at it from my remote explorer, but from my published site it's gone!

```
body {
background-color: rgb(46, 46, 46) !important;
background: url(/assets/images/doginhand.jpeg) no-repeat 50% fixed;
background-size: 100%;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: Can we have a link to the repository?

Comment: this depends on the location of yous CSS file and images

Comment: What errors or warnings are you seeing in you browsers dev tools?

Answer (score 0):

I think your image folder or image missing on the GitHub repository. Please confirm images are moved to GitHub. If I get a repository link It will be easy to help you